# dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5500: connect: connection refused

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, backend

I'm just learning JS for Backend . 
When i load up 'live server' from Visual Code , this happens . I've checked if  5500 is listed for listening and it shows it's listening . 
what seems to be the problem , any clue ?

dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5500: connect: connection refused

Comment: show us some code

Comment: There are an awful lot of factors which can create this kind of issue. It would be useful if you detailed all of the steps you took, and any code you ran, in order to ascertain what your issue might be.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a code issue or a tool issue.  Are you saying Visual Studio is showing you an internal error about that connection or are you saying that your own code is causing this issue?

Comment: @PhilipAdler  Yes I've done that , check the latest answer

Comment: @ArianRahman you have not added the steps you took *before* seeing the error message - that answer you posted is about what you did *afterward* to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to allow port 5500 from the firewall.

Comment: you could be a little descriptive bro... it was my problem too. I allowed that port on windows fire wall its still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using a different browser to see if the problem persists. I had a similar issue while running my JS code via live server on VScode. It throws the same error on Firefox but loads perfectly on Chrome and Brave browser.

A quick walk around is to use a different browser.